# How to Improve a Password Validation Function in PHP: Ensuring Strong Security and Proper Function Typing

Tags: php, security, password-protection, password-encryption

I'm currently developing an admin login page in PHP, which interacts with a MySQL database. To enhance security, I'm focusing on implementing a robust password validation function. However, I've encountered some issues highlighted by PHPStan, particularly related to function typing.

PHPStan reports:

1. "Function **`validate_password()`** has no return type specified."
2. "Function **`validate_password()`** has a parameter **`$password`** with no type specified."

I would appreciate guidance on the following points:

1. What would be the appropriate return type for the **`validate_password()`** function?
2. How should I specify the type for the **`$password`** parameter?
3. Are there any recommended practices or additional steps I could take to strengthen the password validation process?

Below is my current implementation of the **`validate_password()`** function:

```
// Main Password Validation Function
function validate_password($password)
{
  // Password Policy Definition
  $min_length = 8;
  $max_length = 64;
  $require_uppercase = true;
  $require_lowercase = true;
  $require_numbers = true;
  $require_special_chars = true;
  $max_consecutive_characters = 3;
  $pass_length = mb_strlen($password);


  if (!isset($password) || !is_string($password)) {
    throw new Exception('Password must be a string.');
  }

  if ($password === '' || empty($password)) {
    throw new Exception('Password field cannot be empty.');
  }

  // Check Password Length
  if ($pass_length < $min_length || $pass_length > $max_length) {
    throw new Exception('Password length must be between ' . $min_length . ' and ' . $max_length . ' characters.');
  }

  // Check Character Types in Password
  if ($require_uppercase && !preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $password)) {
    throw new Exception('Password must include at least one uppercase letter.');
  }

  if ($require_lowercase && !preg_match('/[a-z]/', $password)) {
    throw new Exception('Password must include at least one lowercase letter.');
  }

  if ($require_numbers && !preg_match('/\d/', $password)) {
    throw new Exception('Password must include at least one number.');
  }

  if ($require_special_chars && !preg_match('/[\W_]/', $password)) {
    throw new Exception('Password must include at least one special character.');
  }

  // Check for Consecutive Characters
  if (hasTooManyConsecutiveCharacters($password, $max_consecutive_characters)) {
    throw new Exception('Password must not contain more than ' . $max_consecutive_characters . ' consecutive identical characters.');
  }

  return $password;
}


// Function to Detect Too Many Consecutive Identical Characters
function hasTooManyConsecutiveCharacters($password, $limit)
{
  $regex = '/(.)\\1{' . $limit . ',}/';
  return preg_match($regex, $password);
}
```

call function when submit

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  try {
    $password = validate_password($_POST['password']);
}
```

Any suggestions or best practices for enhancing the security and efficiency of this function would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: typehint problem, hardly security stuff.

Comment: Since the function is called `validate_password()`, I would expect it to return a boolean saying if it's valid or not. And for the argument, it should be a string, since that's what you expect. But this doesn't really have anything to do with security.

Comment: Have a look in the manual, especially the chapter [Type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php).

Comment: Btw, if you want it to be as secure as possible, why are you setting a max length for the passwords? Sure, a password with 64 character is most likely pretty secure, bit it's still strange to put a limit on it and 64 characters seems a bit arbitrary.

Comment: Creating variables such as `$require_uppercase` isn't really all that helpful. It implies that you might change your mind about this some day in the future, or that you aren't certain about it today.

Comment: My only advice would be to find a library to calculate entropy. These kind of manual rules often get on the way of proper security practices and prevent you from using passphrases or automated password generators built into password managers.

Comment: Obviously `void` because you throw on failure so return doesnt matter and you dont change the password in any way.